# How to handle django.db.utils.IntegrityError for asynchronous POSTs? (Can you except an IntegrityError?)

Tags: django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework

I have a model with a @BEFORE_CREATE signal hook like thus:

```
from django.lifecycle.hooks import BEFORE_CREATE

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.JSONField(unique=True)

    @hook(BEFORE_CREATE)
    def populate_slug(self):
        # Create a slug from the title
        # If the slug already exists, append "-{n}"
        # to make sure it is unique
        slug[0] = slugify(self.title)
        n = 2
        while List.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists():
            slug[0] = f"{slug[0]-{n}"
            n += 1
        self.slug = slug
```

This works fine in my tests when the Items are created synchronously one-after-another:

```
i1 = Item.objects.create(title="Hello")
i2 = Item.objects.create(title="Hello")

self.assertEqual(i1.slug, ["hello"])
self.assertEqual(i2.slug, ["hello-2"])
```

However, on my actual frontend, I'm creating these objects asynchronously and at the same time:

```
const item1 = axios.post(POST_ITEMS_URL, {title: "Hello"})
const item2 = axios.post(POST_ITEMS_URL, {title: "Hello"})
Promise.all([item1, item2]);
```

Which gives me this error:

```
web_1  | django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "app_item_slug_key"
web_1  | DETAIL:  Key (slug)=(["hello"]) already exists.
```

An easy fix (I think) would be to change my @hook to be AFTER_CREATE but I would like to avoid the additional write on all objects if possible.

Is it possible to put an except IntegrityError somewhere? If so, where?

Or how else can I overcome this problem?

I'm using PostGRE if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out where to put the IntegrityError - by overwriting the Item view's create method:

```
# To retry 3 times
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        n = 0
        while n < 4:
            try:
                serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                self.perform_create(serializer)
                headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
                return Response(
                    serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers
                )
            except IntegrityError:
                n += 1
                continue
            break
```

Async POSTs on the frontend now work :)